# Ho to merge Six datatable into one and show date in datagridview without database

Tags: forms, datagridview, datatable

i have six datatable

```
 MyClass1 mc = new MyClass1();   
 DataTable dt = mc.GetNumber(list);
 DataTable dt1=mc.GetPNR(list);
 DataTable dt2 = mc.GetDetail(list1);
 DataTable dt3 = mc.GetDetail1(list1);
 DataTable dt4 = mc.GetDetail2(list1);
 DataTable dt5 = mc.GetDetail3(list1);
```

mc is the object of a class which is used to call function from class on click event of button

Now what I want is when I click on button all the data in those datatable get into one datatable and bind that datatable to datagridview so that when I click on button I can view details in datagridview which comes from the function created in class.

I use merge but it didn't work I search a lot on Google but I didn't get anything that I want so I came here I hope I am clear.